# Spring mvc it, compare payload and header values

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, testing, spring-boot, integration-testing

We have some intergation tests over `@RestController` with a common pattern to verify that an Xpath expression exists and that an Http header is set. But I would like to go further and verify that the XPath value is equald or contained into the header.

```
mvc.perform(..)
  .andExpect(xpath("Item/@id/").isIn(header("Location")))
```

Is it something for that or should I create my own `ResultMatcher` ?

Answer (score 0):

`org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.xpath(xpathExpress, args)` is what you want.
For example:

```
    ResultActions resultActions = mvc.perform(..);
    String location = resultActions.andReturn().getResponse().getHeader("Location");
    resultActions.andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.xpath("Item/@id/", null)
            .string(org.hamcrest.Matchers.containsString(location)));
```

If you need to compare by Node, [XMLUnit for Java 2.x](https://github.com/xmlunit/xmlunit) offers more usefule `Matcher`.

Comment: That looks great but what `header(String)` methdo are you using ?

Comment: Please refer updated answer. You can get response header value by `MvcResult.getResponse().getHeader(headerName)`.